# Powershell to open, edit, save a tab delimited file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to automate a process from beginning to end.

The details of the process, which I'm doing manually, are as follows:

I have a tab delimited file (.tab file extension). The files have a variable number of rows. I'm using excel to open the files and multiply *some* of the columns by -1 to negate their values. After negating the values, I save the file.

I'm looking for a way to automate this process, and though that powershell might be capable of doing so, but my searches haven't yielded much useful information.

Comment: How is this question different from your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39980639/1630171)?

Comment: I didn't do a great job of explaining my desired outcome in the previous one.

Comment: Then you should fix that by editing the existing question instead of re-posting what is basically the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The components you need are:

1. Read the file into an array of strings

   ```
   $content = Get-Content 'file.tab'
   ```
2. Loop over all strings in `$content` and split each by the tabulator -- the result is another array. Loop over that new array and multiply each entry by `-1`. Join the so multiplied array to get back the whole row.After you're finished with all strings, assign the complete result to the original array `$content` again.

   ```
   $content = $content | ForEach{($_.split("`t") | ForEach{-$_}) -join "`t"}
   ```
3. Output the result as you want. e.g. by using the `Out-File` cmdlet,

   ```
   $content | Out-File 'new_file.tab'
   ```

**EDIT:** I did not read the other question which was marked as the original to this duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on this david, much appreciated.